# Ionic 2 get value of dynamic checkboxes

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, checkbox, ionic2, angular2-ngmodel

I am populating checkboxes from my database, and I want the user to be able to complete the checkbox form and submit it back to the database. I am unable to figure out how to get the values of the checkboxes that are populated dynamically. The code is below.

```
export class ListPage {
    checklists: any;
    checkedData: any;
    checklist:any;
    a:any;

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams:
    NavParams, public http: Http, public data: checklistData) {

        this.data.checklistdata().then(result => {
            this.checklists =  result;
            console.log(this.checklists)
        });

        for(this.a=0; this.a>0; this.a++){
            console.log(this.checklist.checked)
        }
    }
}

<div *ngFor="let checklist of checklists; let i=index ">
    <ion-item>
    <ion-label>{{checklist.name}}</ion-label>
    <ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="checklist.checked"></ion-checkbox>
    </ion-item>
</div>

<b>selectedItems</b>: <div *ngFor="let checklist of checklists">{{checklist.checked}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I`ve found a simple solution based on native javascript:

```
let checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName("checkbox");
for ( var i=0 ; i< checkboxes.length ; i++ ) {
  console.log(checkboxes[i].getAttribute("checked"))

}
```